# Parse a decimal while using alpine Docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have a string that I can parse with these statements

```
   var allowedStyles = NumberStyles.Number;

   CultureInfo cultureInfoDe = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

   decimal value = decimal.Parse("10.000,22", allowedStyles, cultureInfoDe);
```

I works running the code inside a Web Api in Kestrel on a Windows machine and if I start it with  the default Dockerfile (`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base`)

If I use aspnet:7.0-alpine I get a System.FormatException.

This is the Dockerfile I am using.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dockerapi.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./././dockerapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./dockerapi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./dockerapi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockerapi.dll"]
```

How can I parse that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install `icu-data-full` to get the German locales installed.

So do

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs icu-data-full
```

and it should work.